# Matching a line without either of two words

Tags: regex

I was wondering how to match a line without either of two words?

For example, I would like to match a line without neither `Chapter` nor `Part`. So neither of these two lines is a match:

```
("Chapter 2 The Economic Problem 31" "#74")

("Part 2 How Markets Work 51" "#94")
```

while this is a match

```
("Scatter Diagrams 21" "#64")
```

My python-style regex will be like `(?<!(Chapter|Part)).*?\n`. I know it is not right and will appreciate your help.

Comment: Watch out: did you want to reject `("Partnerships for Fun" "#118")`?  And, if you have a US orientation, what about `("Recovering from a Chapter 11 Bankruptcy", "#291")`?

Comment: @Jonathan: Thanks! I don't want to reject the first example. What does a US orientation mean?

Comment: 'US-orientation' is a reference to the fact that [Chapter 11 of the US Bankruptcy Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapter_11,_Title_11,_United_States_Code) might not be of much significance to you if you are from Europe or Asia.  Or, alternatively, it means that I had a far harder time coming up with a title that you'd likely want to keep that contained the word 'Chapter'.  Maybe `("Murder in the Chapter-House" "#319")`, but that relies on some curiosities of (Church of England cathedrals, or maybe monastic) [clerical organization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapter_house).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?!.*(Chapter|Part)).*
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! I wonder how to achieve the same by looking backward, i.e. why my `(?<!(Chapter|Part)).*?\n` is wrong?

Comment: At the start of the string it looks backwards to see whether "Chapter" or "Part" is there; neither is, so the negative lookbehind succeeds.

Comment: You don't want to use lookbehind for this anyway.  For one thing, lookbehinds can only match strings with a known, fixed length--for example, `(?<!Chap|Part)` would work, but not `(?<!Chapter|Part)`.  But even if that weren't true (and some other regex flavors are more flexible in that regard), this would still be much easier to do with lookaheads.

Comment: Some regex implementations _do_ support variable-length lookbehinds, for example, the alternative regex implementation for Python at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Answer (score 1):

@MRAB's solution will work, but here's another option:

```
(?m)^(?:(?!\b(?:Chapter|Part)\b).)*$
```

The `.` matches one character at a time, *after* the lookahead checks that it's not the first character of `Chapter` or `Part`.  The word boundaries (`\b`) make sure it doesn't incorrectly match part of a longer word, like `Partition`.

The `^` and `$` are start- and end anchors; they ensure that you match a whole line.  `$` is better than `\n` because it also matches the end of the *last* line, which won't necessarily have a linefeed at the end.  The `(?m)` at the beginning modifies the meaning of the anchors; without that, they only match at the beginning and end of the whole input, not of individual lines.

Comment: Thanks!  Is  `(?m)...` supposed to match multiple lines? Why the regex match single lines?

Comment: Try not to read too much into the name "multiline"; it's been confusing people from the moment it was coined.  The `(?m)` means exactly what I said: that you want the `^` and `$` anchors to match at line boundaries, not at the beginning and end of the input as they normally do.  See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for more info--that whole tutorial is good.